# Python M2Crypto SSL: Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, x509, m2crypto

I am trying to get peer-authentication working using X509 certs/M2Crypto.SSL

1. I generate a root CA (issuer & subject = ca_hostC) on the client (hostC)
2. I sign the client cert locally with this CA (issuer: ca_hostC, subject: hostC)
3. I generate a CSR on hostS, copy it to hostC, sign it using the root CA from step 1 and move the ca_cert and the signed cert to the hostS.

I generate context:

```
import M2Crypto.SSL as SSL
ctx = SSL.Context('tlsv1')
ctx.load_cert('x.crt', 'private/x.key')
ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='ca.crt')
ctx.set_verify ( SSL.verify_peer | SSL.verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert , 0, verify_callback)
```

I connect:

```
s = SSL.Connection(ctx)
s.connect(server_address)
```

but on the client I get

```
ERROR: 20
unable to get local issuer certificate
```

however when I print the subject and issuer of the cert received from the server, I see correct info. Also, the cert is verifiable from the openssl command line util.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

figured it out -- Somehow I thought depth=0 meant infinite depth. 
from [openssl documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html)

depth: *set the limit up to which depth certificates in a chain are used during the verification procedure. If the certificate chain is longer than allowed, the certificates above the limit are ignored. Error messages are generated as if these certificates would not be present, most likely a* X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY *will be issued. The depth count is*

```
level 0: peer certificate, 
level 1: CA certificate, 
level 2: higher level CA certificate,
```

*and so on. Setting the maximum depth to 2 allows the levels 0, 1, and 2. The default depth limit is 9, allowing for the peer certificate and additional 9 CA certificates.*